# SQL adding a field that combines the id and an increment number based on customer

Tags: sql, group-by

I would like to ask the question regarding the title matter.
My current table is look like below:

```
Customer ID    Product ID    Product Name
---------------------------------------------
111            6577          ProductA
111            6123          ProductB
111            2133          ProductC  
111            1123          ProductD    
222            6577          ProductA    
222            6123          ProductB    
222            1578          ProductL    
333            9273          ProductX
```

And the result should look like (with the additional field RefID):

```
Customer ID    Product ID    Product Name   RefID
--------------------------------------------------
111            6577          ProductA       111-1
111            6123          ProductB       111-2
111            2133          ProductC       111-3
111            1123          ProductD       111-4
222            6577          ProductA       222-1
222            6123          ProductB       222-2
222            1578          ProductL       222-3
333            9273          ProductX       333-1
```

I am not very clear what should i do to achieve this?
Could you please help me?

Many thanks

Comment: What SQL database system are you working with?  SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

For SQL server

```
select MT.*, 
       Customer_ID + '-' + row_number() over(partition by Customer_ID order by Product_Name) as RefID
from MyTable MT
```

Oracle

```
select MT.*, 
       to_char(Customer_ID, '99999') || '-' || to_char(row_number() over(partition by Customer_ID order by Product_Name) , '99999')  as RefID
from MyTable MT
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select
exe.costumer_id,
exe.produkt_id,
exe.product_name,
exe.costumer_id || '-' || exe.num
from
(
    select
    costumer_id,
    produkt_id,
    product_name,
    row_number() over (partition by costumer_id order by costumer_id) as num
    from _table
) exe
```

Comment: You keep using that word. I do not think it means what you think it means... [Costumer](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/costumer)

Comment: What do you mean of word ?

Comment: @Abihabi87 i have tried this, but i had one issue, i could not do 'exe.costumer_id || '-' || exe.num' so i tried 'customer_id + num', but im losing the last number of the customer id